# Android Studio Quick Documentation not working in all cases

Tags: android-studio

Using Android Studio, Chipmunk 2021.2.1 Patch 1.

If I use Ctrl+Q on "TextView" in my code, it works nicely and pops up valid documentation.

But when I, for example, press Ctrl+Q when on the **setText()** (and various other areas of code) method, I get the following:

[image: Ctrl+Q for Quick Documentation]

Clicking on "Edit API docs paths" does nothing. Clicking on one of the **setText(...)** links below that opens a web page with "404 Not Found".

I have seen many similar posts here with proposed solutions such as downloading JavaDocs or editing jdk.table.xml (I cannot find that file anywhere on my system) to correctly point to local docs.

I am sure there is a simple solution, but I have been fighting this and reading many posts here for a while, and I can't find it. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Ok - stumbled upon this just now. I don't know if this is the right-way or if the full answer would include more steps, but here is what I did and now it is working.

In my screenshot above, I clicked on the 3-vertical-dots in the lower right of the popup window. And just for grins, I clicked on Edit Source from the menu.

[remembering the steps now that I just did, may be a bit fuzzy]

This opened a window, that complained about files not being downloaded in the upper right. So I clicked on the 'download' link and files downloaded quickly (about 15s). Then I clicked on the Refresh link in the same location.

Then I returned to my edit window and voila! It is now working.

[image: New Help Text]